# Safari not showing visited color for svg icon that is inside an anchor tag

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, visited

Safari is not showing visited color for svg icon that is inside an anchor tag.

The link text shows the visited color, but the svg icon does not. When I inspect the svg in safari, it shows that it should have the visited color, inherited from the link:

[image: Visited color seems to be on]

If I check the computed styles from the inspector, it also shows it should have the visited color:

[image: computed styles]

Is it possible to get Safari to show the visited color for the svg icon?

Safari version: Version 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused. If I go to your demo site and change --visited-link-color to red I can clearly see the icon goes red too. Are you certain the icon isn't changing to the right color?

Comment: Did you go with Safari? The color of the icon is not changing on safari 14.1.1. My colleague has the same issue with safari

Comment: Ah, my mistake! Will try again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this. The icon color was set with `fill=currentColor`. And for some reason Safari did not set the value currentColor correct for the svg when visited state was on. The solution was to add a more specific css selector that targeted the svg path:

```
.hds-link:visited svg g path {
   fill: var(--link-visited-color);
}
```